# What is an alternative to ADO.NET, but elegant way in C# to read Excel files

Tags: c#, excel

ADO.NET just fails miserably when it's used to read Excel files where a column contains mixed data types.  It appears that it tries to determine the data type of a column, and then assume the rest of the entire column is of the same data type.  Here are some backgrounds:

[How to prevent ADO.NET from altering double values when it reads from Excel files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968111/how-to-prevent-ado-net-from-altering-double-values-when-it-reads-from-excel-files)

http://blog.lab49.com/archives/196

What is an alternative approach that doesn't require automation, Excel to be co-installed, is simple (since the input excel file will only have one worksheet in each file).

Comment: depending on your Excel file format, you could to use an OpenXML library to get your data, or to extract that data as XML and consume it directly

Comment: I suppose you could upload it to Google Docs and use their API.  At the very least it should avoid the structuring problems you describe with ADO.

Comment: Exactly which format(s) are the files in? (csv, xls, xlsx, etc)

Comment: @James Manning - I think the answer to your question is **xls**.  The Excel input file is to be created by non-technical users.  They launch Excel, and with an empty file sitting there, they start typing 2 columns of data, hit Save and give it a file name when prompted.

Comment: @ladenedge - Unfortunately, that's not possible.  We can't go outside the firewall with company's information like that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there is a setting that you can specify in the JET provider's connection string to prevent it from trying to infer the data type of a column.  Check out the IMEX=1 setting or the RowsToScan setting:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819.
It's frustrating to get it working, but I think that once you do ADO is probably a pretty good approach to reading Excel files, considering the alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

It depends a little on the Excel versions you need to support. I've used [ExcelPackage](http://www.codeplex.com/ExcelPackage) successfully in the past for reading and creating Excel 2007 files. It is no longer under development, which is a bit of a shame. You'd have to manually loop though all the cells, which I wouldn't call elegant, but it's flexible ;)

Leniel has suggested using [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) over ExcelPackage. I haven't used it myself, but it looks very promising.

There are several other suggestions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444522/import-and-export-excel-what-is-the-best-library), but I have no experience with the other libraries.

Comment: ExcelPackage looks promising.

Comment: @Khnle: After my answer, you added the **.xls** requirement. It doesn't do files older than Excel 2007 (.xslx), but some of these other libraries do.

Comment: I can add support for Aspose, indirectly mentioned in the linked question.  It's expensive, but high quality.  ( http://www.aspose.com/ )

Comment: http://epplus.codeplex.com/ surpasses ExcelPackage. Take a look at it if you plan to work with XLSX format.

Answer (score 2):

I heart NPOI.

http://npoi.codeplex.com/